# Computational methods for wave propagation in unknown non-homogeneous medium.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, numerical-methods, soft-question, computational-mathematics

Say I have some sending devices and receiving devices which I know position of ${\bf r}_k,{\bf s}_k$. Furthermore I can control what is sent on sending devices and when. In other words boundary conditions of the scalar signal $u$ at ${\bf s}_k, {\bf r}_k$. And we assume the wave equation is being followed.

$$\frac{\partial ^2 u}{\partial t^2}=c^2\nabla^2 u$$

But $c$, propagation speed *is not constant, but can vary* over the geometry of the solution.

How can we by varying sending $u({\bf s}_k,t)$, measuring $u({\bf r}_k,t)$ determine $u({\bf x},t)$ and $c({\bf x})$?

I am interested in practical algorithms, but any reference to the mathematics behind such algorithms are welcome as well.

Comment: https://github.com/geodynamics/specfem3d_globe/wiki/01_introduction

Comment: @user14717 it looks more like a piece of software than a reference.

Comment: It is. It's the state of the art for what you are attempting to do, spectral elements, with an implementation. The wiki is a reference.

Comment: I am not interested in that, but the math and algorithms

Comment: Are you asking specifically about numerical methods for solving the inhomogeneous wave equation, exact methods when a solution exists, or measurement techniques, or all of the above?

Comment: @mathreadler, this sounds like the history of underwater acoustics (pun intended).  Please confirm my previous question w/r to what exactly you are looking for, I can provide a laundry list of articles on theory and application, with numeric methods.